# Use regular expression to filter out records

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 (Enterprise) in my project. I have a text column in a table. Values in this column can be numbers such as 5, 3.1, 0.4, etc.

I would like to retrieve records which have numbers in this column. Can I do this with T-SQL in the `where` clause? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `isnumeric()` function to test the value to see if it is a number.  For instance:

```
declare @tbl table (value varchar(20))

insert into @tbl
values ('5'),('3.1'),('0.4'),('this'),('is'),('a'),('test'),('9.2'),('10e-5')

select *
from   @tbl
where  isnumeric(value) = 1
```

Returns:

```
value
--------------------
5
3.1
0.4
9.2
10e-5
```

It even detects exponential notation.